# Ancient Riddle of the In-Between

Tags: riddle

We are the mythical twins
In the in-between place
Gateway to the middle
Where the king's daughter faces the dust
We are of the strong one, the labourer
One of us keeps monkeys

**Who are we?**

Hint 1:

> The monkeys are real, not mythical.

Hint 2:

> Geography.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are:

> The pillars of Herculus, also known as The Strait of Gibraltar

Lines 1-2:
We are the mythical twins
In the in-between place

> The sides of the strait were called "The Pillars of Hercules." According to myth, Hercules created the strait as part of one of his Labors. No-one at the time of myth creation knew what lay beyond the strait, providing one potential meaning of "in-between" place. Alternately, the Pillars of Hercules are often referenced in myth as as supporting the sky, hence they are "in between" earth and heaven (or the mythological equivalent).

Lines 3-4:
Gateway to the middle
Where the king's daughter faces the dust

> The strait is a gateway from the Atlantic Ocean to the Middle East, where Israel, King David's "daughter" is. It is also a desert, hence the dust (this one's a stretch).

Line 5:
We are of the strong one, the labourer

> Hercules is a mythical figure purported to be very strong. Also he underwent the 12 Labors of Hercules.

Line 6:
One of us keeps monkeys

> Gibraltar (on the European side) has the only native monkeys in Europe

Comment: Made some edits based on further reasoning and a little research.

Comment: Great solution! (**Spoiler comments:**) "King's daughter" and "dust" were referring to the [etymology of Europe and Africa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_continent_name_etymologies). "in-between" and "middle" are related to the word "Mediterranean" in addition to the meanings you pointed out. But anyway, that's nitpicking, and your interpretations make just as much sense.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the third and fourth lines. That's something I wouldn't have searched for (though I should have thought of it!). Had I not been to the northern land mass in question (with the monkeys) I might not have gotten this one!

Comment: Thought the question was who are we, didnt focus on what

Answer (score 2):

I've come to 2 different options, but decided on this answer because I believe it has closer clues.

We are the mythical twins

> Quetzalcoatl and Xolotl, mythical twins

In the in-between place
Gateway to the middle

> They are in the underworld but want to escape and create a life

Where the king's daughter faces the dust
We are of the strong one, the labourer

> While trying to run away from the underworld, Quetzalcoatl dropped the bones, and they broke into pieces. He gathered up the pieces and took them to the earth goddess **Cihuacoatl, who ground them into flour**. Quetzalcoatl moistened the flour with his own blood, **which gave it life**. Then he and Xolotl shaped the mixture into human forms and taught the new creatures how to reproduce themselves. So I guess Cihuacoatl represents the holy woman, and since twins do the hard work, they are the labourers.

One of us keeps monkeys

> Quetzalcoatl: In his form as Ehecatl he is the wind, is represented by **spider monkeys**, ducks, and the wind itself.

Comment: what is your other option?

Comment: The Maya Twins was my second thought

Answer (score 0):

They are:

> Heracles & Iphicles

The strong one, the laborer

> Heracles the strong one, plus he had to complete several labours commanded by some king which name i forgot

keeps monkeys

> reference to the Kerkopes Heracles captured

in between

> about having 2 fathers and/or Heracles father being zeus and the mother being mortal

Comment: That's not exactly it, but you're close. Some of your clue interpretations are correct but you need to rethink how they relate to the answer. (Look closely at line 5 of the riddle for example.)

Comment: the word of, but i didn't know he had twins? but he did Antileon and Hippeus

Comment: Yes the word "of" is significant, but no it's not those two...

Comment: alright, i'll do some research, cause my knowledge doesn't go any further then my original answer.

Comment: Updated, if im wrong i will feel like yelling this is Sparta and kick something ;-)

Comment: No, it's still not it, and the idea of going further and further down the family tree doesn't lead in the right direction. Anyway, I added some hints.